# Confused about libjpeg: jpeg_read_scanlines

Tags: c++, jpeg, rgb, libjpeg

I'm confused about the way libjpeg [**`jpeg_read_scanlines`**](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libjpeg.jpeg.read.scanlines.1.html) works.  It's my understanding that it decompresses a JPEG, row by row, and creates a decompressed pixel buffer.

Typical usage is something like:

```
jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

...

unsigned char* image = new unsigned char[cinfo.image_width  * cinfo.image_height];
unsigned char* ptr = image; 
int row_stride = cinfo.image_width;

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.image_height) 
{
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, &ptr, 1);
    ptr += row_stride;
}
```

**Question:** I'm confused about the *output buffer size*.  In all [example code](http://download.blender.org/source/chest/blender_2.03_tree/jpeg/example.c) I see which uses `jpeg_read_scanlines`, the size of the output buffer is `width X height`, where width and height refer to the dimensions of the JPEG file.  So for a 10x10 JPEG file we'd have a 100 byte output buffer.

But... isn't the size of each RGB pixel *3 bytes* (24-bit)?  So shouldn't the uncompressed data actually be `width X height X 3` bytes?

Why isn't it?

I notice that with code which uses `jpeg_write_scanlines`, the buffer to be compressed *IS* `width X height X 3`.  So why is the buffer used with `jpeg_read_scanlines` only `width X height`?

Comment: You are reading the example incorrectly. Pay attention to the `row_stride` variable.

Comment: @n.m., in the example code `row_stride` is `cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;`.  And since `cinfo.output_components` is `1`, row_stride is equivalent to `cinfo.output_width`

Comment: It is only 1 for grayscale images.

Answer (score 3):

You are only reading 1 line at a time with the line

`jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, &ptr, 1);`

so you only needed the line

`unsigned char* image = new unsigned char[cinfo.image_width  * cinfo.image_height];`

to be

`unsigned char* image = new unsigned char[cinfo.image_width  * cinfo.image_components];`

The start of the buffer is being re-used for every scanline.    Most of your current buffer is actually unused.

Answer (score 0):

For RGB data, `output_components` will be 3 (R,G,B).

Here's some related documentation from [libjpeg.txt](https://github.com/Windower/libjpeg/blob/master/libjpeg.txt):

```
   output_width     image width and height, as scaled
   output_height
   out_color_components # of color components in out_color_space
   output_components    # of color components returned per pixel
   colormap     the selected colormap, if any
   actual_number_of_colors      number of entries in colormap

output_components is 1 (a colormap index) when quantizing colors; otherwise it
equals out_color_components.  It is the number of JSAMPLE values that will be
emitted per pixel in the output arrays.

Typically you will need to allocate data buffers to hold the incoming image.
You will need output_width * output_components JSAMPLEs per scanline in your
output buffer, and a total of output_height scanlines will be returned.
```